# Target Username vs Subject Username in windows logs

Tags: windows, logging

When looking at windows event logs, I see 2 kinds of users mentioned: a subject username and a target username.

For authentication logs ( such as 4624 login events ) I understand that the subject username is the user performing the authentication i.e system. And the target username is the user attempting to authenticate.

However, for such logs as process creation ( eventcode 4688 ), who is the subject user and who is the target user?

The only thing I could think of is that if impersonation tokens are used, then the subject can be the user performing the action and the target can be the user on who's behalf the action is being performed. But I don't think that this is the correct answer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [Event ID 4624](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4624) :
`"account was successfully logged on"`

User who is attempting may be Different from User who is logging on.
Hence we have Subject Username & Target Username.

Here is [Event ID 4688](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4688) :
`"new process has been created"`

Some User is starting some new Process. Hence , we have Subject Username.
It may be that the new Process is owned by the same user.
That is when using [CreateProcessA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) , which is very common.

We can also use [CreateProcessAsUserA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasusera) & [CreateProcessWithLogonW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithlogonw) & [CreateProcessWithTokenW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithtokenw) , where we have Target Username.
In these Cases, Subject Username is Different from Target Username.

Here is the C++ Example :

```
BOOL CreateProcessWithLogonW(
  [in]                LPCWSTR               lpUsername,
  [in, optional]      LPCWSTR               lpDomain,
  [in]                LPCWSTR               lpPassword,
  [in]                DWORD                 dwLogonFlags,
  [in, optional]      LPCWSTR               lpApplicationName,
  [in, out, optional] LPWSTR                lpCommandLine,
  [in]                DWORD                 dwCreationFlags,
  [in, optional]      LPVOID                lpEnvironment,
  [in, optional]      LPCWSTR               lpCurrentDirectory,
  [in]                LPSTARTUPINFOW        lpStartupInfo,
  [out]               LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
);
```

In this Case , we have Target Username Details here :

```
  [in]                LPCWSTR               lpUsername,
  [in, optional]      LPCWSTR               lpDomain,
  [in]                LPCWSTR               lpPassword,
  [in]                DWORD                 dwLogonFlags,
```

Hence having Subject Username & Target Username is very necessary even with Event ID 4624 & Event ID 4688.